# HTML userMedia facingMode: "environment"doesn't work on android phone

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, getusermedia

It keeps using the front facing camera instead of the back camera
This is my code: I added the facingMode: {exact:"environment"}, but it doesn't work

```
const constraints = {
    video: true,
    facingMode: { exact: 'environment' }
};

if ('mediaDevices' in navigator && 'getUserMedia' in navigator.mediaDevices) {
    console.log("Let's get this party started")
}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
then((stream) => {video.srcObject = stream});
function displayImage()
{
    const selectedFile = document.getElementById('fileinput')
    //var image =document.getElementById('output')
    //image.src = URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile.files[0]);
    //selectedFile.files[0]
    const img = new Image()
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile.files[0])
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight
    video.style.display="none"
    canvas.style.display ="inline"
    console.log(img)
    console.log("image uploaded")

    img.onload = function() {
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0,video.videoWidth,video.videoHeight);
        console.log('the image is drawn');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constraints are not set correctly.

`facingMode` is a member of the `video` constraint, so it should be

```
const constraints = {
  video: {
    facingMode: {
      exact: "environment"
    }
  }
};
```

[Live Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/map0t5xk/) to be ran from a device with a back camera.

Comment: HAve you tested this? Because this doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Yes I did and it does work for me on both Chrome for Android and FF for Android. And moreover I'm 100% certain it's how the API works. However, since you are using the `exact`  priority mode, if tou try this on a device which doesn't have a back camera it will just not work, as I said, it is "to be ran from a device with a back camera."

Comment: @WannesVanderPerren did you try from the linked fiddle or from your own code? If the former, did you ever blocked gUM from jsfiddle.net? If the latter, double check your code.

Comment: No, I can't tell what's wrong in what I can't read. However I'll note that there are apparently two requests being made from that page. Also, I gave you a working example, use it.

Comment: Yeah you are right, i just overlooked another call... Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2):

The `facingMode` constraint is incompletely implemented, especially in mobile devices.

I have found that the `label` member of the `device` object contains the string `back` for an environment-facing camera and `front` for a user-facing camera in a wide range of mobile devices, android and iOS. (Sometimes those strings are partially in upper case.) So you could do something like this. It's a bit of a hairball compared to `facingMode`, but it works.

```
/* get user's permission to muck around with video devices */
const tempStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true})
const devices = navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
let frontDeviceId
let backDeviceId
if (devices.length > 0) {
  /* defaults so all this will work on a desktop */
  frontDeviceId = devices[0].deviceId;
  backDeviceId = devices[0].deviceId;
}
/* look for front and back devices */
devices.forEach (device => {
  if( device.kind === 'videoinput' ) {
    if( device.label && device.label.length > 0 ) {
      if( device.label.toLowerCase().indexOf( 'back' ) >= 0 ) 
        backDeviceId = device.deviceId
      else if( device.label.toLowerCase().indexOf( 'front' ) >= 0 )
        frontDeviceId = device.deviceId
    }
  }
}
/* close the temp stream */
const tracks = tempStream.getTracks()
if( tracks ) 
  for( let t = 0; t < tracks.length; t++ ) tracks[t].stop()
/* open the device you want */
const constraints = {
  video: true,
  deviceId: {exact: backDeviceId }
}
const stream = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
```

Comment: Some devices may use localized languages such as "前置相機" for user-facing camera and 
 "後置相機" for environment-facing camera.

Comment: I will explore this. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for me is to use "ideal" so it will work both on a pc both on a phone:

```
const constraints = {
  video: {
    facingMode: {
      ideal: "environment"
    }
  }
};
btn.onclick = e => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then((stream) => {video.srcObject = stream})
        .catch( console.error );
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Zibri/pk7en85u/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this works for me, but supporting both desktop and phone conditions works if I *also* define `width` and `height` properties on the constraints:

```
      const constraints = {
        video: {
          width: { ideal: 4096 },
          height: { ideal: 2160 },
          facingMode: "environment",
        },
      }
```

Why this works? I have no idea, but on Chrome on iOS it does as well as Chrome on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on Safari Iphone 6s (I think) was to pass the constraints directly to getUserMedia:

```
const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
    {
        video: { facingMode: { ideal: "environment" } },
        audio: false
    }
);
```